# What is the name for this minimal satisfying set covering problem?

Tags: algorithms, np-complete, combinatorics, minimum-spanning-tree, set-cover

#### Preface

Hello! I have a problem here that's difficult for me to Google, and I don't know if there's a name for it. It feels like a set cover problem of some kind, but I'm very unfamiliar with combinatorics and I don't know all the right words that could apply here.

I'll do my best to describe it below.

(The actual application of this concerns the re-assignment of permission roles in a user/account management system, where the permissions can be grouped together. Anyone familiar with Amazon AWS and the assignment of policies to IAM groups may see where this is going...)

#### Problem

Given a set of elements $U = \{1,2,3,...,n\}$ and a collection $S$ of $m$ sets, where $s ∈ S$ and $s ⊆ U$...

In the following example, $S = \{a,b,c\}$

$a = \{1\}$,
$b = \{1,2,3\}$
$c = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

**Create the smallest number of new sets in $T$ where $a,b,c$ can be redefined as unions of a combination of the sets in $T$.**

#### Solution

$T = \{x,y,z\}$

$x = \{1\}$,
$y = \{1,2,3\}$,
$z = \{4,5\}$

Redefining $S = \{a^*,b^*,c^*\}$:

$a^* = x$

$b^* = y$

$c^* = y ∪ z$

#### Alternative solution

$x = \{1\}$,
$y = \{2,3\}$,
$z = \{4,5\}$

Alternative redefinition of $S$:

$a^* = x$

$b^* = x ∪ y$

$c^* = x ∪ y ∪ z$

---

Comment: @HendrikJan Here $T$ is allowed to contain non-disjoint sets also. So the two problems might be different?

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Oops. Good point! The example in one of the comments to the other question is $\{ \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4\} \}$ makes this clear. Of course three sets suffice, but those are not disjoint.

Comment: @Carson: What do you think? Should we ask to reopen the question?